# Layout not correct

Tags: android, xml, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to make a app for iOS and Android using Visual Studio Xamarin, but the layout does not work at all. This is the layout code I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" x:Class="Test.MainPage" BackgroundColor="Black">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place your controls here -->


        <Label x:Name="TextLabel"
               Text="Title label:"
               TextColor="White"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,250,0,0"
               />

        <Button x:Name="OpenFood"
                Text=""
                TextColor="Yellow"
                FontSize="Large"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                Clicked="OpenFood_Pressed"
                Margin="0,0,0,250"
                />

        <Button x:Name="NewFood"
                Text="  Display label button  "
                BorderColor="Gray"
                BorderWidth="1"
                BorderRadius="10"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="Large"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                Clicked="NewFood_Pressed"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The preview window looks like I want it, but on device, it does not fit at all:
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8RF.png)

EDIT: To tell you what I want: I want the `Display label button` at the bottom of screen, and the `TextLabel` and `OpenFood` in the middle of the screen.

Comment: You are hard coding margins, that is typically not going to work out well with devices of not just differing resolutions but different DPIs.. You should review the different layouts available to you other than just using StackLayout : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the VerticalOptions in Xamarin. You have Fill, Center, FillAndExpand, by adding that to your controls, you can adjust the position within your page.

```
    <Label x:Name="TextLabel"
           Text="Title label:"
           TextColor="White"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           Margin="0,250,0,0"
           />

    <Button x:Name="OpenFood"
            Text=""
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            TextColor="Yellow"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            Clicked="OpenFood_Pressed"
            Margin="0,0,0,250"
            />

    <Button x:Name="NewFood"
            Text="  Display label button  "
            VerticalOptions="End"
            HorizontalOptions="Center
            BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1"
            BorderRadius="10"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            Clicked="NewFood_Pressed"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            />

</StackLayout>
```